# Shrink exponential fraction argument

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fractions

Since the argument becomes too small when using `\frac`, is there an alternative way to reduce the size of the `\exp` argument?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme} 
    \begin{document}

    $$\eta = A \exp^{-\dfrac{E_a}{RT}}$$

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is very rare to need `\dfrac`  rather than `\frac` and certainly not in an exponent

Answer (score 7):

You asked,

> is there an alternative way to reduce the size of the `\exp` argument?

If one uses `\exp` notation, one should *not* raise the argument to superscript height. Instead, simply encase the argument in round parentheses, square brackets, or whatever fence symbols are most suitable to the task.

Separately, to avoid having to display fractional expression in superscript position, do consider using so-called inline-fraction notation. E.g., instead of writing `e^{\frac{u}{v}}`, write `e^{u/v}` -- or `\exp(u/v)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\eta = e^{-E_a/RT} = A \exp(-E_a/RT)
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, don't use `$$ .. $$` for displayed math, use `\[ .. \]` instead. Second, you can make the fraction in the exponent larder than `\frac` in two ways; either expand `-E_a/RT` or use normal size of `\frac` by any of several methods, I here used `\mbox`. `\tfrac` will also do the same but is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme} 
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\eta &= A \exp^{-E_a/RT} \\
\eta &= A \exp^{\mbox{$-\frac{E_a}{RT}$}} \\
\eta &= A \exp^{-\tfrac{E_a}{RT}} \\
\eta &= A \exp^{-\frac{E_a}{RT}}
\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: As Mico explain it, please avoid using a exponent argument with the **function** exp. Either use exponent with the **number** *e*, or use parentheses with the **function** exp.